# Cognito authorization endpoint (without client secret) returning Invalid client error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, terraform, amazon-cognito

I have a problem with Cognito and api clients like Postman or Insomnia.

There is a mobile app that makes calls to the backend.

There is an AWS Cognito instance, with one user pool and one API client, configured for using Authorization Code, with Cognito User Pool set as an Identity Provider

At first, the API client was configured to use client secret. I was able to make API calls from Postman or Insomnia using Oauth2 authentication, but for some unknown reason I wasn't able to authenticate using the mobile app

Then there was a change in the infrastructure - the old API Client entry in Cognito was recreated, but configured **NOT to use client secret**. We immediately removed client secret data from the code. After that, I was able to log in from the mobile application and send requests to the backend, but now I cannot authenticate with Postman/Insomnia. The browser window is opening, I can see the credentials form, I can properly login, but after that when Postman is calling the token endpoint, I get a browser window with one message in it:

> An error was encountered with the requested page.

And I do not receive my tokens. Postman says:

> Authentication failed
> Couldn’t complete authentication. Check the Postman Console for more details.

Insomnia:

> [oauth2] Failed to fetch token url=https://my-app-address.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token status=400

And finally, here's the Insomnia's response timeline:

```
* Preparing request to https://my-app-name.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
* Current time is 2023-01-04T10:56:38.314Z
* Enable automatic URL encoding
* Using default HTTP version
* Enable timeout of 30000ms
* Enable SSL validation
* Enable cookie sending with jar of 2 cookies
* Found bundle for host my-app-name.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com: 0x12f2ee990 [can multiplex]
* Re-using existing connection! (#13) with host my-app-name.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com
* Connected to my-app-name.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com (x.x.x.x) port 443 (#13)
* Using Stream ID: 9 (easy handle 0x14e9f8400)

> POST /oauth2/token HTTP/2
> Host: my-app-name.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com
> user-agent: insomnia/2022.7.0
> cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=f1264cb4-b688-41a3-9126-cf021df2fa30
> content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> accept: application/x-www-form-urlencoded, application/json
> authorization: Basic MzJkN2JvnzNhNUTzNGNIN3UzdjY5b3Zkb246ZXI=
> content-length: 166

| grant_type=authorization_code&code=9e3e6ae8-30c7-6c5c-9aee-1930131a6624&redirect_uri=myapp%3A%2F%2Ffrontpage&code_verifier=dhQD1EtvMm_yP6eGorgQU7budSloaspeuGUM_OzS34k

* We are completely uploaded and fine

< HTTP/2 400 
< date: Wed, 04 Jan 2023 10:56:38 GMT
< content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
< x-amz-cognito-request-id: 71156586-7bd3-4485-944c-07b5b930ce15
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
< cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
< pragma: no-cache
< expires: 0
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
< x-frame-options: DENY
< server: Server


* Received 26 B chunk
* Connection #13 to host my-app-name.auth.eu-west-1.amazoncognito.com left intact

| {"error":"invalid_client"}
```

And the cognito user pool config:

```
resource "aws_cognito_user_pool_client" "my_app_client" {
  name         = "my-app-dev"
  user_pool_id = aws_cognito_user_pool.default.id

  allowed_oauth_flows                  = ["code"]
  allowed_oauth_flows_user_pool_client = true
  allowed_oauth_scopes                 = ["email", "openid"]

  callback_urls = ["myapp://frontpage"]
  logout_urls   = ["myapp://signout"]

  supported_identity_providers = ["COGNITO"]
}
```

What could be the reason why I am unable to authenticate using Postman/Insomnia and receive such errors? Could this be something related to AWS configuration? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not configured the *client secret* in the App client, `authorization` header should not be added in the token request.

As mentioned in the [document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html), `authorization` header needs to be provided only if the client was issued a secret.

Comment: Please make sure you expand your answer with examples and/or documentation.